# Removing alternate sections of a singly linked list where each node points to two objects

Tags: java, pointers, while-loop, stack, singly-linked-list

I'm working with a Singly Linked List with nodes of type Segment, and each segment points to a position and a color. My list describes a caterpillar, so I want no discontinuities - i.e. if I remove the 2nd, 4th, and 6th segments of a 7-segmented caterpillar, I want the 3rd segment to take the position of the 2nd, the 5th to take the position of the 3rd, etc. so that there are no "holes". But of course I want the new 2nd segment to retain the color of the 3rd. Finally, I want to add all the positions I am no longer using - like the last 3 positions that the 5th, 6th and 7th segments pointed to - to my stack called previouslyOccupiedPositions.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
     // the caterpillar devours a slide of Swiss cheese, losing half of its segments.
     public void eat(SwissCheese cheese) {
        if (this.length <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        Stack<Position> positionsKept = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Position> positionsRemoved = new Stack<>();
        Segment temp = this.head;
        boolean removeSegment = false;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (!removeSegment) {
                positionsKept.push(temp.position);
            }
            else {
                positionsRemoved.push(temp.position);
            }

            removeSegment = !removeSegment;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        this.length = (this.length +1)/2;

        this.head = new Segment(positionsKept.pop(), this.head.color);
        Segment curr = this.head;

        while (!positionsKept.isEmpty()) {
            curr.next = new Segment(positionsKept.pop(), curr.next.next.color);
            curr = curr.next;
        }

        while (!positionsRemoved.isEmpty()) {
            positionsPreviouslyOccupied.push(positionsRemoved.pop());
        }
    }
```

Does this make sense? I particularly have a problem with the last chunk of code where I assign head to a new object of type Segment, and afterwards.

Comment: Do you want to delete the alternative nodes of the linkedList and save the deleted nodes to a stack.?

Answer (score 0):

You have a classical problem of **remove an item from the single linked list**. This is not depend on the item's data.

You should define a class of the container. And internal item representation (a node with data and reference to the next node). And finally implement the delete method.

How to delete a randome method from the single linked list:

1. Find the item (e.g. `A`).
2. Find the previous item (e.g. `preA`)
3. Find the next item (e.g. `nextA`)
4. Change reference from `preA -> A` to `preA -> nextA`
5. Remove reference `A -> null`

So your container could look like this:

```java
public final class SinglyLinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> head;

    public void add(T data) {
        if (head == null)
            head = new Node<>(data);
        else {
            Node<T> node = head;

            while (node.next != null)
                node = node.next;

            node.next = new Node<>(data);
        }
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    private static final class Node<T> {

        private final T data;
        private Node<T> next;

    }

}
```

And then, e.g. in case you want to remove every `2nd` element, then it could look like this:

```java
public List<T> removeEvenItems() {
    if (head == null || head.next == null)
        return List.of();

    boolean remove = false;
    Node<T> prv = null;
    Node<T> node = head;
    List<T> removed = new ArrayList<>();

    while (node != null) {
        if (remove) {
            removed.add(node.data);
            prv.next = node.next;
            node.next = null;
            node = prv.next;
        } else {
            prv = node;
            node = node.next;
        }

        remove = !remove;
    }

    return removed;
}
```

Or remove every `1st` elements:

```java
public List<T> removeOddItems() {
    if (head == null)
        return List.of();

    if (head.next == null) {
        T data = head.data;
        head = null;
        return List.of(data);
    }

    boolean remove = true;
    Node<T> prv = null;
    Node<T> node = head;
    List<T> removed = new ArrayList<>();

    while (node != null) {
        if (remove) {
            removed.add(node.data);

            if (prv == null) {
                head = node.next;
                node.next = null;
                node = head;
            } else {
                prv.next = node.next;
                node.next = null;
                node = prv.next;
            }
        } else {
            prv = node;
            node = node.next;
        }

        remove = !remove;
    }

    return removed;
}
```